# How to ask user permission in iphone to sent push notfication in ibm worklight

Tags: iphone, permissions, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Hi we are developing IBM Mobile first platform hybrid application In our app we are using push notification to sent notification to the user, for this we need to ask permission from the user to sent notification in IPHONE, for this we are creating simple dialog box and asking permission from the user but here my question is if click on don't allow button how we need to handle that, and also if the user disable notification settings in mobile how we need to handle that scenario.

Comment: when a push enabled application is deployed on the device for the time , the OS pops-up a native dialog asking the user to allow or not allow notifications.Are you trying to override this behaviour? Or ask the question everytime?

Comment: No i am overriding it, how can we use that native dialog box, i am not able to find solution for that

Comment: I think this answers your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930953/how-to-display-photo-library-permissions-dialog-in-cordova